# Set operation in c++(update existing value)

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
 while (it!=s.end())  //here 's' is a set of stl and 'it' is iterator of set
    {   
        *it=*it-sub;    //'sub' is an int value
        it++;
    }
```

I can't update the value of set by iterator. I want to subtract an integer value 'sub' from all the element of set.

Can anyone help me where the actual problem is and what would be the actual solution?

Here is the error message:

```
error: assignment of read-only location ‘it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>::operator*()’
   28 |             *it=*it-sub;
      |             ~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mre].

Comment: Elements in set can be only read. By modifying one, you would reorder other items in set.

Comment: The solution is to erase the iterator and insert a new one with key `*it - sub`. Please, note that `std::set::erase()` returns a new iterator which has to be used in your case to keep the `while` loop working properly.

Comment: @Scheff Can you do that while you are ierating over a set? Could it not end up in an endless loop? Especially when doing something relevant to the curently iterated set which puts visited elements where they will be visited again?

Comment: Note, you can only accept ONE answer. Pick the most helpful one from your point of view.

Comment: Imtiaz Out of curiosity, in case there is a follow up for this assignment, could you report it here in a comment (I assume this is an assignment without meaning anything bad by it, your question is fine)? As you can see in my comments on Scheff answer, I am speculating about the teachers larger plan with this. Just curiosity.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Key values of elements in a `std::set` are `const` for a good reason. Modifying them may destroy the order which is essential for a `std::set`.

Hence, the solution is to erase the iterator and insert a new one with key `*it - sub`. Please, note that `std::set::erase()` returns a new iterator which has to be used in your case to keep the while loop working properly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::set<T> &values)
{
  const char *sep = "{ ";
  for (const T &value : values) { out << sep << value; sep = ", "; }
  return out << " }";
}

int main()
{
  std::set<int> test{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
  std::cout << "test: " << test << '\n';
  const int sub = 10;
  std::set<int>::iterator iter = test.begin();
  while (iter != test.end()) {
    const int value = *iter;
    iter = test.erase(iter);
    test.insert(value - sub);
  }
  std::cout << "test: " << test << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
test: { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
test: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bf6d372e4565a6f)

---

Changes on the `std::set` while iterating over it are not a problem in general but can cause subtle issues.

The most important fact is that all used iterators have to be kept intact or may not be used anymore. (That's why the current iterator of the erase element is assigned with the return value of `std::set::erase()` which is either an intact iterator or the end of set.)

Of course, elements can be inserted as well behind the current iterator. While this is not a problem concerning the `std::set` it may break the loop of my above example.

To demonstrate it, I changed the above sample a bit. Please, note that I added an additional counter to grant the termination of loop:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::set<T> &values)
{
  const char *sep = "{ ";
  for (const T &value : values) { out << sep << value; sep = ", "; }
  return out << " }";
}

int main()
{
  std::set<int> test{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
  std::cout << "test: " << test << '\n';
  const int add = 10;
  std::set<int>::iterator iter = test.begin();
  int n = 7;
  while (iter != test.end()) {
    if (n-- > 0) {
      const int value = *iter;
      iter = test.erase(iter);
      test.insert(value + add);
    } else ++iter;
  }
  std::cout << "test: " << test << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
test: { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
test: { 23, 24, 25, 31, 32 }
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fc8bdaac37a8f89)

Comment: Is it possible that this only works for subtracting something, but could end up in an endless loop if the operation causes reinsertion at a place where it will be visited later.... ?

Comment: @Yunnosch Beside of the danger for infinite loop, there is no problem to insert iterators behind the current iterator. Iterators are stable in the `std::set`. It might be necessary to consider the border case that the new iterator is inserted directly behind the erased. - It will be skipped after insertion in the loop.

Comment: In C++17, you can `extract` nodes, modify their keys, and return them back into to set. It would be more efficient, since it avoids unnecessary allocations.

Comment: Could you elaborate "It will be skipped after insertion in the loop.". I think I do not get your point there.

Comment: @Yunnosch Bad wording. If a new inserted element is considered in current loop depends on whether it is before or after the iterator which is returned by `erase()`. So, it might appear behind the erased element (though it has been erased) but will be skipped as the iteration will continue with the old successor of the now erased element. - Hope, you got my message. I'm afraid I cannot explain better. Otherwise, stick to _std::set iterators are stable._ ;-)

Comment: That is good explanation of an interesting mechanism. May I propose to [edit] and improve the answer with it? I think it improves the answer because the question seems to relate to the first step of a teachers scheme to make students aware of this, where the second step would ask for a minute change (e.g. the operation to be done on each element) which will make the program fail. This is of course speculation. But consider the teachers face when they find a program which is robust against step 2... :-)

Comment: Note the detail of my worry: Not only inserting right after the current element might cause an endless loop, also at the "end" of current sorting. The operation to be done on each element could be fine-tuned in step two to do exactly that.

Comment: @Yunnosch Done. (I needed a while to get this running because I stumbled into an issue with `if (n--)` (doesn't work) while `if (n-- > 0)` does that made me my head scratching. However, that's actually unrelated to the above topic.)

Comment: Another issue is that the value of a subtracted element might be the same as one of the yet-unprocessed values in the `std::set`. Since you cannot have the same element twice, the insertion will just leave the `std::set` unchanged and you will lose the element later. Consider for example the input set: `{10, 20, 30}` with `add = 10`.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Though all these issues are actually not an issue with `std::set` or its `iterator`s but rather with the algorithm which is "made around". However, nice observation.

Comment: Could `test.insert(value + add);` be changed to `test.insert(iter, value + add);`? Since they're subtracting, the new value definitely precedes `iter`, and it should turn a `O(log n)` unhinted `insert` cost into a `O(1)` hinted `insert` cost, making the overall cost of the whole operation `O(n)` rather than `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 6):

Simple to just replace it with another set

```
std::set<int> copy;

for (auto i : s)
    copy.insert(i - sub);

s.swap(copy);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't mutate elements of `std::set` by design. See

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin

> Because both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators (and may in fact be the same type), it is not possible to mutate the elements of the container through an iterator returned by any of these member functions.

That is because set is **sorted**. If you mutate element in a sorted collection the collection must be sorted again, which is of course possible, but not the C++ way.

Your options are:

1. Use another type of collection (unsorted).
2. Create a new set and fill it with modified elements.
3. Remove an element from `std::set`, modify it, then insert again. (It is not a good idea if you want to modify every element)

Answer (score 4):

A `std::set` is typically implemented as a self-balancing binary tree in STL. `*it` is the value of the element which is used to order the tree. If it was possible to modify it, the order would become invalid hence it isn't possible to do that.

If you want to update an element, then you have to find that element in the set, remove it and insert the updated value of the element. But since you have to update values of all elements, then you have to erase and insert all elements one by one.

It is possible to do it in one for loop provided `sub > 0`. `S.erase(pos)` removes the iterator at position `pos` and returns the following position. If `sub > 0`, the updated value which you'll insert will come before the value at the new iterator in the tree but if `sub <= 0`, then the updated value will come after the value at the new iterator in the tree and hence you'll end up in an infinite loop.

```
for (auto itr = S.begin(); itr != S.end(); )
{
    int val = *itr;
    itr = S.erase(itr);
    S.insert(val - sub);
}
```

Comment: That's a good way ...I think it is only way to do that.just delete and again insert.

Answer (score 3):

The error pretty much explains the problem

Members of `std::set` container are `const`. 
Changing them make their respective ordering invalid.

For changing elements in `std::set`, you will have to erase the item and re-insert it after it is changed.

Alternatively, you could use `std::map` to overcome this scenario.