# Removing & Adding elements in STL While Using Iterators

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator, invalidation

I am confused by an excerpt from the book I'm reading.

[image: Excerpt Part A]

[image: Excerpt Part B]

I don't understand why the book justifies using removal and addition operations to an STL even though it results in iterator invalidity. Can someone clarify to me the message the book is trying to deliver?

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_" - I can't read your picture but if I'm to guess, they use the fact that `erase` returns a valid iterator to the element after the erased element.

Comment: It's about a `std::set` but the issue is similar. FYI: [SO: Set operation in c++(update existing value)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764290/7478597)

Answer (score 2):

The point the author is trying to make, is that while `vector::insert` and `vector::erase` may invalidate previously created iterators, the ones they return are necessarily valid, so you can rely on them.

Check this table to know exactly when iter/ref invalidation happens for each STL container: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Answer (score 2):

Even though these operations invalidate (some of the) old, pre-existing iterators, that doesn't prevent newly created iterators from being valid. The example program assigns ("resets" in words used by the text) the value of the invalid iterator with a valid value.

Here is a different, but analogous example:

```
int* ptr;     // an iterator

{
    int i;
    ptr = &i; // ptr is now valid
} // ptr has become invalid because storage duration of i ended

int j;
ptr = &j; // ptr is valid again despite having been invalid earlier
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example the return value of `insert` and `erase` are assigned to `iter`. Both methods invalidate existing iterators into the container, but the iterator they return is a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

For starters starting at least from the C++ 14 Standard you may use the constant iterator `const_iterator`  in member functions `erase` and `insert`.

Now the corresponding member functions (used in your code snippet) are declared like

```
iterator insert(const_iterator position, const T& x);
iterator erase(const_iterator position);
```

So you may write

```
auto iter = vi.cbegin();
```

instead of

```
auto iter = vi.begin();
```

and use it in calls of `erase` and `insert`.

After adding a new element into a vector using the member function `insert` the vector can internally reallocate memory for its elements. In this case the current iterator can be invalid because it will point to the memory before its reallocation.

But the function returns an iterator that points to the newly inserted element stored in the already reallocated memory. Thus the returned iterator will point to the actual extent of memory.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    
    v.insert( v.cbegin(), 0 );
    
    std::cout << "v.data() = " << v.data() 
              << ", &v[0] = " << &v[0] << '\n';
    
    v.insert( v.cbegin(), 1 );
    
    std::cout << "v.data() = " << v.data() 
              << ", &v[0] = " << &v[0]
              << ", &v[1] = " << &v[1] << '\n';
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
v.data() = 0x556699d79e70, &v[0] = 0x556699d79e70
v.data() = 0x556699d7aea0, &v[0] = 0x556699d7aea0, &v[1] = 0x556699d7aea4
```

So as you can see after inserting the second value the vector reallocated internally the memory where the elements are stored. That is before inserting the second value the current iterator returned by the function `cbegin` pointed to the extent of memory with the address `0x556699d79e70`. After inserting the second value the current iterator returned by the function `cbegin` will point to the extent of memory with the address `0x556699d7aea0`. That is the previous current iterator become invalid.

But if you will rewrite the program the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto iter = v.cbegin();
    
    iter = v.insert( iter, 0 );
    
    std::cout << "v.data() = " << v.data()  
              << ", &*iter = " << &*iter << '\n';
    
    iter = v.insert( iter, 1 );
    
    std::cout << "v.data() = " << v.data() 
              << ", &*iter = " << &*iter << '\n';
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then as it is seen from the program output

```
v.data() = 0x55d8c5698e70, &*iter = 0x55d8c5698e70
v.data() = 0x55d8c5699ea0, &*iter = 0x55d8c5699ea0
```

the iterator `iter` always points to a valid extent of memory because it was reassigned by the iterator returned by the function insert that as a result points to the valid extent of memory.

The same is valid for the member function `erase`. The returned by the function iterator is invalidated.